# Cannot serve react app - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

i am trying to serve a build from create-react-app with nodejs + express

when accessing the site on the first render every thing works fine 
but when i am trying to reload the page lets say on this url : http://localhost/auth/login
i am getting this error :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 1.24b58957.chunk.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  main.ee83e24f.chunk.js:1

my node server :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use('/media', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'build/static/media')));
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
});
app.listen(port)
```

its seems that when serving js files the index.html is serve and causing the problem

i tried every post i can find on that issue but no luck

what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you solve the problem? If yes, could you please explain how? I faced this problem just now. Before removing some media from my assets, everything was working fine, after that I ran `yarn build` and then `serve -s build` and faced this error.

Comment: My problem is just solved! You don't believe if I say the only problem was the Internet connection that was disconnected! Just connected to another access point and the problem solved